# python glob file exist or not

Tags: python, glob, file-exists

```
testIDs=subprocess.Popen('ls cskpiSummary-310410-LTE-K-M2M-L-*UE1* | cut -d"-" -f7 | uniq', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
try:
        os.chdir(QMDLPath)
except OSError:
        print 'QMDL Directory not found'
        exit()

for testID in testIDs.stdout:
        for file in glob.glob("*"+testID+"*"):
                print file
```

Would someone be able to point out what am I doing wrong here? The testIDs = subprocess extracts a list of testIDs(e.g: 20150422111035146). I want to use that as a pattern to see if file exists or not under QMDLPath directory which I have changed through chdir. If it is "NOT" present, print that test ID otherwise print a message that no files are missing.The sample file name will be diag-20150422111035146-server1.txt

Comment: Why not use `glob` from `import glob` or `import glob2` instead of `sub process`ing ls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [find file name which does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837910/find-file-name-which-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading in a line from the pipe and that line includes the newline.  When that is included in the glob statement it doesn't match anything.  You just need to strip the whitespace from the end of the string.  Replace the for loop line with:

```
for file in glob.glob("*"+testID.rstrip()+"*"):
```

Comment: It worked. :) But this lists the file which are present. I am trying to find those testIDs for which the file is not present.